I want to see if a cell has a text with other text in it
I want to get a count of the cells that contain a word, but that have other words in them too, like Yes, depends should count with cells that just have yes. The Yes in the first part should count with the yes by itself but with this formula: =COUNTIF(Raw_Data!$AA$11:$AA$65,"Yes")
I'm stuck on this homework assignment trying to make statistical data look better to write a report on it.



Use Wildcard Operator * --> =COUNTIF(Raw_Data!$AA$11:$AA$65,"*Yes*")

Without using wildcards =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes", Raw_Data!$AA$11:$AA$65)))


Yes in the first part should count with the yes by itself but with this formula: =COUNTIF(Raw_Data!$AA$11:$AA$65,"Yes")

Adding a wildcard will match "Yes" with additional characters following.  This technique was also mentioned in the comments section by @mayukh-bhattacharya here.
=COUNTIF(Raw_Data!$AA$11:$AA$65,"Yes*")
//                                  ^---- Add a wildcard

Some words of caution:

This is NOT case sensitive.  It will match "Yes", "YES", "yes", etc.
This will ALSO match the text "Yesterday"
This will NOT match the text " Yes".

Since Microsoft 365, you may instead use REGEXTEST, which can be used to expand on the pattern matching.  Google Sheets also supports a similar function.
// Excel
=REGEXTEST(B6, "\bYes\b")

// Google Sheets
=REGEXMATCH(B6, "\bYes\b")
//               ^-----^ match word boundaries


This IS case sensitive.  It will NOT match "yes" or "YES".
If you choose to use a regular expression match, you may add an additional column to calculate this value, then to later then be calculated by =COUNTIF(...).


Just FYI: REGEXTEST is still a preview function. MS does not recommend using these functions in important workbooks until they are generally available
